# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '***' with pnpm

Tags: node.js, webpack, pnpm

After I removed 'shamefully-hoist=true' in `.npmrc`. `pnpm` throws several errors when webpack is building.
After research, I found out that webpack will search modules under different levels of `node_modules`. The program is using `pnpm` and all the modules are moved under `root/node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules`, so webpack can't find the right path of modules and throws errors.

I use two solutions in webpack config to fix this.

solution1: add these modules in

```
resolve: {
  fallback: {
    ***: false // or require.resolve('buffer')
  }
}
```

solution2: add modules

```
modules: ['node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules']
```

These two solutions can both fix this issue. After reading some issues from **github**, I still don't know why webpack can't resolve these modules.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this issue when config webpack

```
resolve: {
  symlinks: true //default value
}
```